# Automating Chrome WebDriver - Select Date from DatePicker using PowerShell and Selenium

Tags: powershell, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

Many thanks to:

- https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-i/
- https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-ii/
- https://tech.mavericksevmont.com/blog/powershell-selenium-automate-web-browser-interactions-part-iii/

for aspiring me to automate Chrome to perform a redundant task that I perform everyday.

I wish that I could select a date instead of sending keys to a datepicker using Selenium in PowerShell.

As per [this weblink](https://www.edureka.co/community/53564/select-from-datepicker-with-selenium-webdriver-using-python) this is how they do it using Python. The task is very simple and PowerShell is bloat-free when it comes to dependencies.

Here is the story with all sorts of error which I am unable to solve:

```
$URL = "https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/"

[OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions]$ChromeOptions = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions
$ChromeOptions.PageLoadStrategy = "eager"
$ChromeOptions.addArguments('start-maximized')
$ChromeDriver = New-Object -TypeName "OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver" -ArgumentList @($ChromeOptions)

$ChromeDriver.Navigate().GoToURL($URL)

$Frame = 0
$SelectFrame = $ChromeDriver.SwitchTo().Frame($Frame)

$SelectFrame.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='datepicker']").click()

$SelectDate = "15"
$dateWidget = $ChromeDriver.FindElementById("ui-datepicker-div")
$cols = $dateWidget.FindElementByTagName("td")

foreach ($cells in $cols) {
    $date = $cells.getText() 
    if($date -eq $SelectDate) {
        $cells.FindElementByLinkTest($date).click()
        break
    }
}

Pause
Function Stop-ChromeDriver {Get-Process -Name chromedriver -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Stop-Process -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
$ChromeDriver.Close()
$ChromeDriver.Quit()
Stop-ChromeDriver
```

Would it be possible using PowerShell too?

Comment: Is this a native browser date picker or a JavaScript says picker? Is it is a JavaScript date picker, you will need to tell us which one and provider the HTML for it, because it will require some custom code to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the blog mentions, I honestly don't know how I got across your question, but I did while googling something else. It's totally doable in PowerShell, try it like this after you've loaded Selenium's class.

```
$ChromeDriver.Navigate().gotourl('https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/')
# The following changes the frame, won't give an ugly error out if it fails:
try {$ChromeDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(0) | Out-Null} catch {} 
$ChromeDriver.FindElementsById('datepicker').click()
# For the following, [2] is the month you pick, [2] == March
$ChromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div/a[2]/span").click() 
# For the following, "10" picks the day of the month, in this case, the 10th
$ChromeDriver.FindElementByLinkText("10").Click()
```

Peace! - M6k